# How do I write test cases for my AWS Python-based lambda project?

Tags: python, automated-tests, aws-lambda

I have implemented a lambda project which has 4 modules/project inside it. Each module/project has python(s) files which implement module functionality.

I have to write the test cases for each module so that it goes through `CircleCI` and execute on themselves:

1. That the module is starting and stopping a stepfunction.
2. module is calling Rest service.
3. It is writing/reading files from S3 Bucket.

Everywhere, it is like a test driven development to write unit test, but now I have completed project implementation, how do I write automated test cases for my module ?

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to unit testing, there's nothing special you have to do about AWS Lambda projects.

You Lambda handler is a Python function. Therefore, you can import it on your tests, call it with some input, and assert the output. Just like a normal Python function.

Comment: i was referring to ppl using aws resource mock

Comment: Then, state that in your question.